# Set xticklabel overlaps old xtick

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to modify the x-ticks of a plot, but one of the tick labels automatically generated by matplotlib does not disappear, and the one I assign overlaps it. The code is:

```
ax[0].plot((zspace+1.),dndt_vs_z_9, color='blue', label=r'$M_s = 10^9$')
ax[0].plot((zspace+1.),dndt_vs_z_10, color='red', label=r'$M_s = 10^{10}$')
ax[0].plot((zspace[zspace<=2]+1.),dndt_vs_z_11[zspace<=2], color='green', label=r'$M_s = 10^{11}$')
ax[0].plot((zspace[zspace<=2]+1.),(1./2.)*dndt_vs_z_11[zspace<=2], color='black')
ax[0].plot((zspace[zspace<=2]+1.),0.65*dndt_vs_z_11[zspace<=2], color='black')
ax[0].plot(gomez_11_x,gomez_11_y,color='blue', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].plot(gomez_10_x,gomez_10_y,color='red', linestyle='dashed')
ax[0].plot(gomez_9_x,gomez_9_y,color='green', linestyle='dashed')
#ax[0].scatter(ill_shmr_z,ill_shmr_dndw_model_11)

ax[0].set_yscale('log')
ax[0].set_xscale('log')

ax[0].set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5], minor=True)
ax[0].set_xticklabels([1,2,3,4,5], minor=True, fontsize='20')
ax[0].set_xlim([1,5])
ax[0].set_ylim([1e-2,1e1])
ax[0].legend(loc='best', fontsize='20')

ax[0].grid(b = True, which='major')
ax[0].grid(b = True, which='minor', axis='x')
ax[0].set_xlabel(r'$1+z$', fontsize='15')
ax[0].set_ylabel(r'$\frac{dN}{dt}$', fontsize='20')
```

and the result is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here comes from mixing major and minor ticks when using log scale. A solution in your example case would be to remove the major ticks using a [`NullLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator) and only use the minor ticks:

A small example would be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(12,7))

ax1.loglog([1,2,3,4,5])
ax1.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5],minor=True)
ax1.set_xticklabels([1,2,3,4,5], minor=True, fontsize='20')
ax1.set_title("Reproduce problem")

ax2.loglog([1,2,3,4,5])
ax2.set_xticks([1,2,3,4,5],minor=True)
ax2.set_xticklabels([1,2,3,4,5], minor=True, fontsize='20')
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator())
ax2.set_title("Apply fix")

plt.show()
```

[image]